# Ajax sourced data using jQuery DataTables

Tags: php, json, ajax, mongodb, datatables

I want to display one of my collections of MongoDb into the table using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) plugin.

However, I got the pop-up message as shown below:

> Requested unknown parameter '0' for row0, column 0. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

The following partial code selects the `job id`, `title`, `submitted` and `status` columns from the `jobs collection`, in the MongoDb procedural way:

**submit.php**

```
$filter = ['user_id' => $_SESSION['google_id']];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);

try {

    $cursor = $manager->executeQuery($dbname.'.'.$collection, $query);
    $arr = array();     
    foreach($cursor as $c){         
        $temp = array("job_id" => $c->job_id, "title" => $c->title, "submitted" => $c->submitted, "status" => $c->status);
        array_push($arr, $temp);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

and displays it within HTML page:

**jobs.php**

```
<table id="tableJobs"></table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      data: "",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resultData) {
          var opt={
            "bProcessing":true,
            "aoColumns":
            [
                {"sTitle":"Submission"},
                {"sTitle":"Title"},
                {"sTitle":"Submitted On"},
                {"sTitle":"Status"}
            ],
            "aaData": resultData
         };         
       $("#tableJobs").dataTable(opt);
       }
     });    
});
</script>
```

What steps I missed out? How can I get it to show all the JSON data source from the db in a HTML table like this:

```
<tr>
<td>F37CE14A-506C-24E7-EBDC-362216BB9089</td>
<td>Demo</td>
<td>2017-03-01 06:47:03</td>
<td>Finished</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do your database rows have any null or empty column values anywhere?

Comment: @Yolo The empty value is not shown. Here's my JSON format:
`[{"job_id":"BB520E08-A183-CBEB-BAE2-006056169116","title":"LA001","submitted":"2017-03-12 11:27:41","status":"Running"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is exactly the problem (at least what datatables docs say). Somewhere in your rows you seem to have empty or null values. Try to initialize initialize them as an empty string.

```
$job_id = !empty($c->job_id) ? $c->job_id : '';
$title = !empty($c->title) ? $c->title : '';
$submitted = !empty($c->submitted) ? $c->submitted : '';
$status = !empty($c->status) ? $c->status : '';

$temp = array("job_id" => $job_id, "title" => $title, "submitted" => $submitted, "status" => $status);
```

Also you need to tell the browser what to expect, namely JSON. So add a header function before outputting your data:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // add this line here
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**UPDATE**

So looking at the documentation of datatables, you need to set your column identifiers using the property "mDataProp" on "aoColumns" object. Then set those declared keys as your array keys in your result. See the fiddle below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var resultData = [
    {"Submission":"BB520E08-A183-CBEB-BAE2-006056169116","Title":"LA001","Submitted On":"2017-03-12 11:27:41","Status":"Running"},
    ];
    var opt={
            "bProcessing":true,
            "aoColumns":
            [
                {"mDataProp":"Submission"},
                {"mDataProp":"Title"},
                {"mDataProp":"Submitted On"},
                {"mDataProp":"Status"}
            ],
            "aaData": resultData
         };         
    $("#tableJobs").dataTable(opt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="tableJobs"></table>
```

Correct this snippet:

```
$temp = array("job_id" => $job_id, "title" => $title, "submitted" => $submitted, "status" => $status);
```

To this one:

```
$temp = array("Submission" => $job_id, "Title" => $title, "Submitted On" => $submitted, "Status" => $status);
```

You will still need this line before you echo anything:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // add this line here
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: I got the same error message after initializing all variables.

Comment: Sorry, this solution is not working for me. Btw, the error message `Requested unknown parameter '{parameter}'`, which is an integer equal to `0`.

When {parameter} is an integer, DataTables is looking for data from an array. In this circumstance the requested data doesn't exist in source array - likely because the array isn't long enough. (at least what datatables manual say), but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, If yes then I googled in the wrong keywords and apologize for that. Is there any other solution? Thanks again!